# AS3 - how to stop instances and movieclips when clicked on button to go to a different 'page'

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have created an application which allows the user to click on several buttons. Each of these buttons have different content on the seven frames.

For example; I have a game on button one, an animation on page 2, etc. The code for all seven buttons is only located on frame 1. When I click on a different button, the games continues to play the next page animation. 
How could I stop that?

p.s the animations/game code is set on different frames ("PAGES AS" layer)

[image: timeline pages setup]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the automatic playing stop, you can add the `stop()` function. This needs to be added to every frame.

If you want to perform a certain action depending on your current frame, you can use:

```
if(stage.currentFrame==AnyNumber){
  //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also you *gotoAndStop(frame number)*.

For example if you press button when its on 1st frame and you want the button to go on 4th frame use *gotoAndStop(4);*